# Super type with flexible functionality

Tags: c#, oop, object, interface

How can I implement this:

- I have 3 types (actually Interface): A , B and C
- A has no methods, but B and C have some methods.
- I want the type A in some situations can be cast to type B and use B methods and in other situation cast to type C and use its methods?

Comment: What you're describing is considered to be bad design: it violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: yes, that's a bad design. I should think again. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    interface A { }
    interface B :A { void b(); } // B inherits from A
    interface C :A { void c(); } // C also inherits from A

    static void Main()
    {
      // declare vars

      A a = null;
      B b = null;
      C c = null;

      // a can happily hold references for B.
      a = b;

      // To call B's methods you need to cast it to B.
      ((B)a).b();


      // a can happily hold references for C.
      a = c;

      // To call C's methods you need to cast it to C.

      a = c;
      ((C)a).c(); 
    }
}
```

---

From your comments

```
class Program
  {
    private interface A { }
    private interface B : A { string b();}
    private interface C : A { string c();}
    class BClass : B { public string b() { return "B"; } }
    class CClass : C { public string c() { return "C"; } }

    private static void Main()
    {
      A a = null;
      B b = new BClass();
      C c = new CClass();
      a = b;
      ((B)a).b();
      a = c;
      ((C)a).c();
    }    
  }
```

Comment: private interface A{}
private interface B : A{string b();}
private interface C : A{string c();}
class BClass : B{public string b(){return "B";}}
class CClass : C{public string c(){return "C";}}

private static void Main()
{
A a = null;
B b = new BClass();
C c = new CClass();

a = b;
((B)a).b();

a = c;
((C) a).c();}